How to enable CORS with NEXT 14 at Vercel?
I have an api endpoint, and I want it to be accessible from any domain name (everyone can use it from web on their domains).
import { NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import path from "path";
import { promises as fs } from "fs";

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const response = Response.json({ data: "test" }, { status: 200 });
  /*...*/
  response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
  response.headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
  return response;
}

export async function OPTIONS(request: Request) {
  const allowedOrigin = request.headers.get("origin");
  const response = new NextResponse(null, {
    status: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": allowedOrigin || "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    },
  });

  return response;
}

It works when I run it on localhost and try to access it from another chrome tab.
But when I host it on Vercel and try to access the api from another domain, I get the following

"next": "14.2.3",  "react": "^18",
Is there any way to enable CORS for this api endpoint? Thanks.

"Is there any way to disable CORS for this api endpoint?" - that's not what you want to begin with. You want this to be consumable from every possible origin, so you want to enable CORS.

The error message in the tooltip in your screenshot there suggests that the issue has to do with the preflight request getting a redirect response - which I'm guessing, is not happening on your local dev system? Then you need to go and figure out, why the redirect happens, when you deploy this via Vercel.

@CBroe Thanks, I've edited the question. Yes, I don't have any errors on my  local dev, only at Vercel

I think you need to use NextResponse.json in the option as well (not new NextResponse)
